# Dynamically Adding Spinner Via java in android

Tags: java, android, dynamic, spinner

I am currently trying to get a function working similar to how adding phone numbers work in your android phone contact list. What I mean by this is that if a contact has more than one phone number you can click the + button and it adds another field to the display for another number.

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks a + button it adds a new spinner right below the existing spinner with the same data in it. I'm not quite sure how to go about creating the spinner to appear below the existing spinner but still above all the content below the existing spinner. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post some code?  What it will come down to is grabbing the ViewGroup that contains the row with your spinner, and then adding a new row via [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int))

Comment: @tdn120 sure I can post some code. I'm gonna check out ViewGroup. How my xml currently looks like is that each section or I guess "Group" is in its own LinearLayout